# Google Cloud Endpoints non WebApp iOS Client Blobstore

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, blobstore

I am trying to create a blobstore upload process for a GCE Application coded in Python.

I do not have a webapp to use the blobstore_handlers process.

What is the process for upload blobs in this manner?

I have implemented the create upload URL endpoint:

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore


def blobstore_get_upload_url(self, request):

    upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
    return self.construct_valid_response(StatusResponse, upload_url)
```

The URL returned is not a valid route on the APP:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/upload/ag1kZXZc3RyaW5nLWltciILEhVfX0Jsb2JVcGxvYWRTZXNzaW9uX18YgICAgICAgAsM
```

When I try to POST to this URL I get this error:

```
The url "/api" does not match any handlers.
```

My app.yaml:

```
handlers:
# Endpoints handler
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
    script: app_api.APPLICATION
```

My question:

Do I need to create a separate script outside of my endpoints application to upload the blob to? Or is there a way to direct the upload URL to another endpoints method to handle the upload process?

When I try to specify a another endpoint on the app as the upload URL it is ignored.

EX:

```
upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/api#p/Api/v1/api.app.blobstore_upload')
```

Note I have removed the app name from the above URL and replaced it with API, but the URL I am using is a valid URL in the app.

I see that the old file process is deprecated and replaced with the google cloud storage process. Is this the direction I should be heading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using the gcs API functions:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions

EX:

```
default_retry_params = gcs.RetryParams(initial_delay=0.2,
                                   max_delay=5.0,
                                   backoff_factor=2,
                                   max_retry_period=15)

gcs.set_default_retry_params(default_retry_params)

bucket_name = os.environ.get('BUCKET_NAME',
                         app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())

gcs_file = gcs.open('/' + bucket_name + '/' + str(c.key.id()) + '/' + request.image_key,
                    'w',
                    options={'x-goog-meta-creator': str(u.key.id()),
                             'x-goog-meta-image-key': request.image_key,
                             'x-goog-meta-container': str(c.key.id())})

gcs_file.write(base64.b64decode(request.encoded_image))
gcs_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Blobstore upload [works in several steps](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore):

1. Create a one-time upload url via `create_upload_url(callbackUrl)`. Send this to client.
2. Client **MUST** then use `multipart/form-data` POST request to upload data to that Url.
3. Google extracts the contents, stores it into blobstore and then calls your `callbackUrl`. You need to have a handler defined on that Url. Handler receives the blobstore keys Google created for the content uploaded.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The process makes sense to me. But can it be done without a webapp2 with routes? I can create a upload URL using one endpoint, but can another cloud endpoints method act as the upload URL?

Comment: Surely not as upload url - those are one-time urls generated by google. Maybe as upload handler url (callback url) but I doubt it.

Comment: The upload URL is fine, the image is making it into the Blobstore. Its the redirect URL I am having issues with. The redirect URL needs to point to a endpoints method that can handle the rest of the process. Did it not occur to them that people may not be using sessions and webapps? I do not have a front end webapp on my current API. Its simply a service for mobile apps.

Comment: Is there any recommendation on how to store images then?

Comment: So far the only way I found to allow uploading of files is to create a webapp just for the serve and upload endpoints. I am passing URL params on the upload URL created by create_upload_url and ensuring this webapp is using secure: always. The URL params passed is the key to a user object, and access_token. On the webapp methods I implement the User model and verify the access token matches that of the user passed in. I think this is hackey. I will investigate the GCS file upload process some more.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great post on using Blobstore with an iOS client. The example is in Java so please comment if there are difficulties recreating the backend code in Python.

https://brunofuster.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/uploading-an-image-from-iphone-to-appengine-blobstore-using-vraptor/